# Meta Properties in AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

In AWS Neptune I was exploring to add meta properties (properties for properties) to vertices as described [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties).
Upon trying I found that Neptune throws an error:

```
Req - {"gremlin":"g.V(v).properties('name').hasValue('host-123').property('acl','private')"}
Response - 
{
"detailedMessage": "Properties on a vertex property is not supported",
"requestId": "a72b1552-aa9e-42aa-8a38-103b3acdde32",
"code": "UnsupportedOperationException"
}
```

I also went through AWS Neptune docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) and it says

> Neptune does not support Gremlin variables and does not support the bindings property.

Are they both the same and does anyone have an idea if meta-properties supported by AWS neptune?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta Properties (properties on properties) are not supported by Amazon Neptune at this time.

Gremlin "variables and bindings" is a reference to submitting scripts to a server as text where the server compiles the script and saves it for future repeated use with different parameters (variables). Neptune has its own query optimizer and execution engine so those kind of bindings are not necessary when working with Neptune.